# Magento2 : Model LSD in Loop

Tags: magento2, magento-2.2.5

I try to get list category with **load()**, but I got the error messages on code editor.

```
phpcs: Ecg.Performance.Loop.ModelLSD: Model LSD method load() detected in loop
```

This is my code :

```
public function getCategory()
{
    $product = $this->getCurrentProduct();
    $categories = $product->getCategoryIds();

    foreach ($categories as $category) {
        /** @noinspection PhpDeprecationInspection */
        $cat = $this->category->load($category);
        $catTree = $cat->getName();
    }
    if (!empty($catTree)) {
        return $catTree;
    }
    return true;
}
```

How to fix this error messages? should I change the method to get category list?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of loading the full category just to get the name, you can inject `Magento\Catalog\Api\CategoryRepositoryInterface` via [constructor dependency injection](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/extension-dev-guide/depend-inj.html) and use `get()` method of this class which will return you the object of `Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\CategoryInterface` and here you can use `getName()` method to get the category name.

Using load inside is not Magento recommended practice and also there is no need to load the whole category just to fetch the name.